# Using a script that opens vim in terminal instead of gvim (is ita bad idea?)

Tags: bash, vim, arguments

On my system i only have vim installed, not gvim. I am also using qutebrowser. In qutebrowser you can set a command to open your editor to edit some text. Due to how it quotes commands, it seems not to work to just directly setting the command as "urxvt -e vim" as it will quote that and pass other options after (ie might execute `'urxvt -e vim' '-f' /home/user/.config/qutebrowser/config.py -c 'normal 1G0l'`). So i made this little script which i called `gvim` (is this name bad practice?) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
terminal="urxvt"
exit $($terminal -e vim "$@")
```

It seems to work as intended, however i'm worried if this might be bad practice or anything can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you show apart from:

```
exit $($terminal -e vim "$@")
```

`exit` here will get the *output* of the command, not the exit status. This is stored in `$?` after the command exits. You could skip the exit command and just call `$terminal -e vim "$@"`.

But isn't there an even simpler solution? Couldn't you just use `urxvt` as command and pass all the rest as arguments? (I have no way to test it, sorry.)

As for your name `gvim` - such application is distributed as `vim-gui-common` in Debian, so it might be another alternative (even on a differnt OS).